# TDD behavior testing with no getters/setters

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm applying TDD to my first event centric project (CQRS, Event sourcing etc) and I'm writing my tests according to Greg Young's simple testing framework Given, When, Expect. My test fixture takes a command, commandhandler and aggregate root and then tests the events outputted.

```
CommandTestFixture<TCommand, TCommandHandler, TAggregateRoot>
```

For example here is a typical test

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_moving_a_group : 
     CommandTestFixture<MoveGroup, MoveGroupHandler, Foo>
```

I am very happy with these tests on the whole but with the the above test I've hit a problem. The aggregate root contains a collection of groups. The command `MoveGroup` reorders the collection, taking a from & to index. I setup the test and asserted that the correct `GroupMoved` event was generated with the correct data.

As an additional test I need to assert that the reordering of the Groups collection actually took place correctly? How do I do this when the aggregate root has no public getters/setters. I could add a method to retrieve the group at a particular index but isn't this breaking encapsulation simply to be testable?

What's the correct way to go about this?

**EDIT**

The reordering of the groups takes place in the GroupMoved handler on the Aggregate root.

```
private void Apply(GroupMoved e)
{
    var moved = groups[e.From];
    groups.RemoveAt(e.From);
    groups.Insert(e.To, moved);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friction here comes because you want to assert something about the internal implementation, but what you have at hand is at the top level.

Your tests and assertions need to be at the same logical level.  There are two ways to re-arrange this:

**What effect does re-ordering groups have on subsequent commands or queries which you do have at the top level?**

This should give you an avenue for asserting that the correct outcome occurs without needing to assert anything about the ordering of the groups directly.  This keeps the test at the top level and would allow all sorts of internal refactoring (e.g. perhaps lazy sorting of the groups).

**Can you test at a lower level?**

If you feel that testing as described above is too complicated, you might want to frame your test at a more detailed level.  I think of this like focusing in on a section of detail to get it right.

Down at this level (rather than your composite root), the interfaces will know about groups and you'll have the opportunity to assert what you want to assert.

**Alternatively, do you need this test at all?**

If you can not find a suitable test at either of the above levels, then are you sure you need this test at all?  If there is no visible external difference then there is no need to lock the behaviour in place with a test.

Comment: Interesting. At present the ordering has no affect on subsequent commands that I can see. It's simply an aesthetic change made by the user to give things priority. My update, remove, edit commands don't project any state that i can test so I can't use these an an avenue. Re lower level testing, the handle method on the AR is what actually does the reordering, I still don't see how I can test at a lower level in it's current implementation.

Comment: @madcapnmckay What would break in your application if the group was not re-ordered?

Comment: At present I guess nothing. I see what you are saying, if nothing breaks, why do we need a test. If something were to break I could target the test at the break.

Comment: @madcapnmckay Yes. Perhaps if you did two re-orderings in a row then the second one would raise an event with the wrong information?